# How to call webservice in Javascript for Firefox 3.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, asmx

I have a problem with calling .Net web services with a Firefox
client. A simple example will be enough for me.

Server side code is like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
return "Hello World";
}
}
```

Client side .html code:

```
Hello World Denemesi<br />
type="text" disabled="disabled" /></td> 
value="Print"           onclick="print()"> </td>
```

Client side .js code:

```
var callObject;
function init(){
service.useService( "Service1.asmx?WSDL","Service");
callObject = service.createCallOptions();
callObject.async = false;

}
function print(){
callObject.funcName = "HelloWorld";
var oResult = service.Service.callService(callObject );
if( !oResult.error )
{
edtHelloWorld.value = oResult.value;
}
}
```

This web service works on IE but doesn't run at firefox because
webservice.htc (behaviour file) doesn't work for firefox. I need a
javascript or something like that wihch I cann use instead of htc
file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to consume your web service in NET, I would suggests using ScriptService,
The client API is easier and should be working on most browsers, see below for a sample:

```
namespace XXX.Services 
{  
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")] 
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
    [ToolboxItem(false)] 
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService 
    { 
        [WebMethod] public string HelloWorld() 
        { 
            return "Hello World"; 
        } 

        [WebMethod] public string Greet(string name) 
        { 
            return "Hello " + name; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Client side html code:

```
Hello World Denemesi
<button onclick="test1()">print</button>
```

Client side .js code:

```
<script>
    function test1(){
         XXX.Services.HelloWorld(function(result){
            alert(result);//do something with the result
         });

         XXX.Services.Greet("John Cane",function(result){
            alert(result);
         });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery ajax calls, they make calling web services easy.  See here: http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/