# Sql Database Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

Hi i have a sql database server runnin on my desktop.  I want to create an asp.net application to detect when new data has been inserted into the database.  Is there a command in visual studio to detect when theres new data right away?

Comment: are you using caching in your application?

Comment: Assuming you're using MSSQL?  You might want to modify your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28SQL.80%29.aspx) datatype on each column.  This will stay identical until a change is made to *any column in that row*.  If you combine this with the rowcount you can be certain if anything has changed in your database.  You would need to cache the current timestamps and row count and compare them with the results of a query, you can then find out if there is a change.

So in your answer to:

> Is there a command in visual studio to
>   detect when theres new data right
>   away?

Yes there is, although its not a command is the [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28SQL.80%29.aspx) function (not to be confused with anything to do with the time)

Perhaps you need to provide more details to your scenario since constant querying of the database might not be the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a row count of your dataset and create a application

**IN VB**

```
Dim i as Integer
i=dataset.tables("table").rows.count
```

in sql backed return a count of a  table and create a ASP.Net website to get the count and when count change alerts you

Comment: this is not what user464111 is asking. he cant check row count again and again for new insertion. this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using caching you can make it dependent on sql.

or you can fire email using sql trigger so when ever trigger get fired you will receive an email.

otherwise you will have to check your db again and again for any changes.

if you can provide more details about exact situation , we can provide more specific solution

You can create a webservice and call it using javascript.
here you can find sample how to call webservice using javascript:

```
 function CallWebservice()
{
 myWebService.isPrimeNumberWebService.callService(isPrimeNumberResult, "IsPrime", 
  testValue.value);
  setTimeout("CallWebservice()",100);//here set time according to your requirement
}
```

For timer in javascript:
http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/09/timer-in-javascript.html

For webservice in javaScript:
http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/020715.html

[How to call webservice in JavaScript for FireFox 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571430)

Comment: I have some measurements that gets sent to the database server, I want to create an asp.net application so it display the measurement on a textbox everytime new measurements get written to the database

Comment: @user464111: then its better to create a web service and use it using ajax and call it using timer. so that only relevant data will be updated on page.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Are you doing all these edits manually? or some auto stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It may be heavier duty than you are looking for, but SQL Notification Services will do what you want. Essentially you execute a query and tell notification services you want to be notified whenever re-running that query would produce different results.