# Webservices method in C# via Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asmx

I am trying to call a webservice method from .aspx page thro' javascript & i get this error, i do have [WebMethod] on the top of the c# method. 
    
        
            Unknown web method [object Object].
Parameter name: methodName

```
    <h2> <i>Unknown web method [object Object].<br>Parameter name: methodName</i> </h2></span>
```

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
    <br><br>

    <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method [object Object].<br>Parameter name: methodName<br><br>



[ArgumentException]: Unknown web method [object Object].
Parameter name: methodName
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.CreateHandler(WebServiceData webServiceData, String methodName)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.CreateHandler(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the exception you received, but you need to show the code. At a guess, is your method `static`?

Comment: then create an example service that has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

1 - I think that your answer is there:
[How to call webservice in Javascript for Firefox 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571430/how-to-call-webservice-in-javascript-for-firefox-3-0)

It illustrates the use of [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()] 
using a very easy and clean code and style.

---

2 - Alternativelly, you could use jQuery as illustrated in this answer: 
[How to use jQuery to call an ASP.NET web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230401/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service)