# How can i get a .net webservices with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net

I have the following code it only works in IE6:

```
if(document.getElementById("IsOnline").value == 'True')
                {
                    var mailBox = document.getElementById('CurrentMailBox').value;

                    var callObj = service.createCallOptions();
                    callObj.async = false;
                    callObj.params = new Array();
                    callObj.params.messageID = pmid;
                    callObj.params.mailBoxID = mailBox;
                    callObj.funcName = "GetPrivateMessageDetail";

                    var xml = service.svcIOra.callService(callObj);

                    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml.value);

                    toUserNames = getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "s_id_to_list");

                    fromUserNames = getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "s_id_from_list");
                    msgAttachment = getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "attachment_name");
                    attach_id = getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "attach_id");
                    msgBody = getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "msg_text");

                    //check to see if private message is invite message
                    var cfid = getNodeValue(xmlDoc, "confToJoin");
                    document.getElementById('ConferenceToJoin').value = cfid;

                    document.getElementById('JoinButton').style.display = (cfid!='') ? "inline" : "none";
                    document.getElementById('RejectButton').style.display = (cfid!='') ? "inline" : "none";
                }
```

How can I make this work in Modern day browsers??

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: What is `service`? How is it created? Why use `Microsoft.XMLDOM`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call webservice in javascript for firebox 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571430/how-to-call-webservice-in-javascript-for-firebox-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following or just try Googleing "Calling Webservices from javascript"

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr